Toilet leaking and mysterious clog
Okay let's start from the beginning. I ended up with both of my toilets not functioning. I called and had the septic tank dumped and this did not fix the problem. Call the plumber he came out removed the toilet in the master bathroom and snaked it. He got that line clear but the laundry room toilet was still not flushing. So he went back and snaked it and it seemed to be working. 30 minutes after he left it again was not flushing. The masterbedroom toilet continued to function. He came back out the next day. Removed the laundry room toilet and had it flushing again.
after a couple days it failed again. I thought things were going well other than the fact that the LR toilet only periodically tries to flush. 3 weeks later water is STARTED leaking out from underneath the master bedroom toilet. I have recently discovered that after emptying the toilet the water was still coming up whenever I use the kitchen sink. My house is on a slab and all of the plumbing is in a central location. I pulled the toilet but I really don't know where to go from here. I had gone into the kitchen to do dishes and came back to again A wet floor. I have had a plumber out here three times now and no one seems to be able to figure this out.
Adding...it also leaks out from under it when flushed.But hadn't for about 3 weeks.

With a septic tank you are not dealing with long distances.  Wax rings are usually single use only, so the leak might be there if it was not replaced with a new one, each time the toilet/s were removed.  Possible the vent pipe is blocked, which might lead to not complete flushing.  With two toilets, the problem should be in the common areas, main drain to the septic tank or the vent.

If water comes up in the drain to the toilet, when you use the kitchen sink there is a clog in the main waste drain to the septic tank.   If you have large trees in your yard, there may be roots invading the line.  There should be a cleanout near the house adjacent to the septic tank.  If you take off the cap and water comes out, the clog is between the cleanout and the septic tank.

Thank you. Sadly there is no clean out. In 30 plus years I have never found one. Plumber said my lines are ABS so it cannot be tree roots?

Crip659i was told both wax rings were replaced. Since I have had the line snaked twice...I'm wondering what kind of clogged.  Re clogs? Also if I need to spend yet more $$$ for video inspection and/or hydro jetting?

Wax rings are not designed to survive hydrostatic pressure, they often leak during complete blockages that are downstream of the toilet. I would consider a different plumber who specializes in drain cleaning; with the problems you have, the line should have been inspected via camera (at least on the 2nd visit). Almost certainly it's the main line, time to have it dug up and have a (2-way) cleanout installed.

ABS does not mean no tree roots can get in. ABS is more fragile than PVC and not uncommon for it to crack and hair like roots grow into the crack until the pipe is almost fully blocked. Time for a different plumber or a company that specializes in drain cleaning.  I myself had a similar issue. First plumber told me to get a utility sink. The second plumber cleaned out the clog and fixed the problem.

Jimmy....you must have missed the part where I said my house is on a concrete slab.. can't dig anything up...it's all down through the concrete. The first time I needed the septic emptied the service and i spent a very long time searching for the tank. They poured the garage floor (concrete) over it.I would have never bought this house..

RMDman. Definitely not using the same plumber. Thanks for  the response.
